# Unable to make parent li active on click of child li with bootstrap in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have search and try different method like using JQuery Helper class etc but i can't find solution for my scenario. My code is below I want Active li when i user select and page refresh

```
<aside class="main-sidebar" style="background: #102C4B none repeat scroll 0% 0%;border-right: 1px solid #DCE1E4;">

    <section class="sidebar">
        <div>
            <ul id="menu" class="sidebar-menu">

                <li class=" treeview">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i style="color:#fff" class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span style="color: #fff;">Dashboard</span> <i style="color:#fff" class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu" style="background: #224775 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
                        @*<li class="active"><a style="color:#fff" href="~/Dashboard/Index">Dashboard</a></li>*@
                        @Html.MenuItem("Dashboard", "Index", "Dashboard")


                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href=" #">
                        <i style="color:#fff" class="fa fa-pie-chart"></i>
                        <span style="color: #fff;">Sales</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right" style="color:#fff"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu" style="background: #224775 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
                        @*<li><a style="color:#fff" href="~/Sales/index"> View Sale</a></li>*@
                        @Html.MenuItem("View Sale", "index", "Sales")

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i style="color:#fff" class="fa fa-laptop"></i>
                        <span style="color: #fff;">Invoice</span>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right" style="color:#fff"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu" style="background: #224775 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
                        @*<li><a style="color:#fff" href="~/Invoice/Index"> View Invoice</a></li>
            <li><a style="color:#fff" href="~/Invoice/Create">Add Invoice</a></li>*@
                        @Html.MenuItem("View Invoice", "Index", "Invoice")
                        @Html.MenuItem("Add Invoice", "Create", "Invoice")
                    </ul>
                </li>



            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>

</aside>
```

The Helper class that i am using is also below but i don't work for me to keep the li open.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class Utilities
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                 string text, string action,
                                 string controller,
                                 object routeValues = null,
                                 object htmlAttributes = null)
{
var li = new TagBuilder("li");
var routeData = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData;
var currentAction = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
var currentController = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
if (string.Equals(currentAction,
                  action,
                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
    string.Equals(currentController,
                  controller,
                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    li.AddCssClass("active");
}
if (routeValues != null)
{
    li.InnerHtml = (htmlAttributes != null)
        ? htmlHelper.ActionLink(text,
                                action,
                                controller,
                                routeValues,
                                htmlAttributes).ToHtmlString()
        : htmlHelper.ActionLink(text,
                                action,
                                controller,
                                routeValues).ToHtmlString();
}
else
{
    li.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(text,
                                         action,
                                         controller).ToHtmlString();
}
return MvcHtmlString.Create(li.ToString());
}
}
```

Comment: Ali, have you tested my answer?

Comment: thanks I checked it today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things to do, one is make the active selection when user clicks and the other is save this selection after the page refreshs right?

If you want to make li selected after the page refresh you need to save this state somewhere. You can save it in client-side (Cookies and Local Storage) or in Server-side (Session or other structures). 
If you choose client-side, you may find some cross-browser problems, some old browsers don't have Local Storage feature for example, or problems with security using Cookies. 
If you choose server side you don't have those problems, but you will use more roundtrips (to save the state for example). But I think this downside is not that critical.

Whatever you choose, will be something like this:

1. on `li` click, you save the parent that need to be selected and apply css class you want and remove the same class from other `li`s.
2. on page rendering, check if the selected parent was saved earlier and then apply css if you need.

Check this sample that I used to test what you need.

```
 <aside>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="treeview">
            Test 1
            <ul >
                <li><a id="A1" runat="server" href="#">Home1</a></li>
                <li><a id="A2" runat="server" href="#">About1</a></li>
                <li><a id="A3" runat="server" href="#">Contact1</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br />
        </li>
        <li class="treeview">
             Test 2
            <ul >
                <li><a id="A4" runat="server" href="#">Home2</a></li>
                <li><a id="A5" runat="server" href="#">About2</a></li>
                <li><a id="A6" runat="server" href="#">Contact2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br />
        </li>
         <li class="treeview">
             Test 3
            <ul >
                <li><a id="A7" runat="server" href="#">Home3</a></li>
                <li><a id="A8" runat="server" href="#">About3</a></li>
                <li><a id="A9" runat="server" href="#">Contact3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

</aside>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.treeview').find('li').each(function (i, e) {
            $(this).click(function (event) {
                $('.treeview').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');

                // TODO: save the index or ID of the selected element. You can do something simple, like a post to action to save the state.
            });
        });

        // TODO: check if the index or ID of the selected element is saved somewhere, then apply the css class you want. 
        // You could make a get to a action to retrieve the state, but is one more roundtrip just to get the state. 
        // Another solution is on the server side, during the rendering, you already know the state of the selected item, so just add the class where you need it.
    });
</script>
```